# The Small Set Expansion Hypothesis, this problem was solved or is open problem yet?

Tags: machine-learning, math, optimization, data-science, statistical-ai

I found this problem by article called "Ten Lectures and Forty-Two Open Problems in the Mathematics of Data Science" published at 2016. I`m looking for an open problem at Data Science or/and Machine Learning field that use many Analysis Math and I'm new in this fields. Anybody can answer about? I looking for any paper the about possibility solved this problem, but I can't find any paper published definitively solved about this problem...

Thanks!

Comment: How about a reference or a link to the paper you mention? Problems can have partial solutions, and sometimes depend on exact specification

Comment: In this paper, https://people.math.ethz.ch/~abandeira/TenLecturesFortyTwoProblems.pdf, at the chapter 3, has a conjecture 3.10. This conjecture is called Small-Set Expansion Hypothesis. A saw this problem have many analysis and has strong relationship with machine learning. I interested in this problem, but this paper was published in 2016... I trying looking for any other current paper that said about solution of this problem, but I can't find and I don't know if I'm looking for correct form....

Comment: one idea is to e-mail the author, most authors are very happy to answer emails regarding their work.